# VNC client viewer versus server

Tags: vnc

My application will trigger a terminal window to run some task. It does open the window when running under VNC server side since its display port number is 0.
When the application runs in VNC client viewer, the terminal windows will not be opened since the display port is not 0. 
In order to fix this issue, I need to know where my application is running at either on Server or Client, so I can set it to the correct display port.

Thanks!
Tom

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: sort of a programming question. I like to know if there is a system command or some information within VNC that can tell me whether my application is running at either client or server.